# How to enable this radio button

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML form, if city flag is 1, disable the 2nd radio button. If city flag is 2, disable the 2nd radio button. If the city flag is 3, enable both buttons.

But when city flag is 3, when I click the 2nd radio button and go next and then came back to the previous widow shows the 1st radio button as checked. I would expect the 2nd button to be checked; not the 1st.

So, I applied city flag 2 function for this as below JavaScript code. Now keeps 2nd radio button selected when go next and go back, but 1st radio button is disabled. I want to enable this radio button without effecting city flag 2 features. Please help on this..

```
$("#reserve_type1").click(function () {
    $("#city_flg").val("1");
});

$("#reserve_type2").click(function () {
    $("#city_flg").val("2");
});
```

form,

```
if ($row['reserve_type_id'] == 1) {
    ?>
    <input type="radio" checked="" name="reserve_type" id="reserve_type1" value="<?php echo $row['reserve_type_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['reserve_type_name'] ?>&nbsp;
        <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="radio" name="reserve_type" id="reserve_type2" value="<?php echo $row['reserve_type_id'] ?>"  ><?php echo $row['reserve_type_name'] ?>&nbsp;
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    } else {
        if ($selected_input_array['city_flg'] == $row['reserve_type_id']) {
            ?>
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="reserve_type" value="<?php echo $row['reserve_type_id'] ?>"  ><?php echo $row['reserve_type_name'] ?>&nbsp;
        <?php } else if ($row['reserve_type_id'] != 3) { ?>
            <input type="radio" name="reserve_type" disabled="true" value="<?php echo $row['reserve_type_id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['reserve_type_name'] ?>&nbsp;
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fiddle or more code?

Comment: what is city flag?  please add your rendered html

Comment: Excuse me, but am I taking it wrong? `If the city flag is 3, enable both buttons`, these are **radio** buttons you can't check both of them! Maybe you should use **checkboxes** instead.